# "NoSuchFieldError: qTESLA_I" with JcaContentSignerBuilder

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Most basic example:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

public class NoSuchFieldDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JcaContentSignerBuilder builder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA384withECDSA");
  }
}
```

throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: qTESLA_I
>       at org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.(Unknown Source)
>       at NoSuchFieldDemo.main(NoSuchFieldDemo.java:5)

PS #1: The code, including the somewhat "magic" String `"SHA384withECDSA"`, comes from ["The Bouncy Castle FIPS Java API in 100 Examples"](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf).

PS #2: This persists after adding a `BouncyCastleFipsProvider` as most-preferred security provider:

```java
// position is 1-based:
final int mostPreferredPosition = 1;
final int actualPosition = Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider(), mostPreferredPosition);
```

PS #3: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.3+7 in case that's important

I guess it's most obvious, but what am I doing wrong?

## Update

I have got `bcpkix-jdk15on` on my classpath in order to have `JcaContentSignerBuilder`. @george-stanchev suggested that this might interfere..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't have non-FIPS jars in your classpath. This can happen if you use non-FIPS bcpkix and FIPS bcprov. The non-FIPS bcpkix statically tries to add those qTESLA algorithms that are defined in bcprov, but the FIPS bcprov does not have those defined hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I do have `bcpkix-jdk15on` on my classpath, but without that I do not have `org.bouncycastle.operator.*`, so no `JcaContentSignerBuilder` either...

Comment: Ah, there's a [`bcpkix-fips`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-fips) which seems to work! Thanks again